# Can not modify response in afterRemote hook in loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

i have a model that uploads a file with some data in the field. All i want to do is to upload the file and take the file path as string and make a create query to another model and send back the response with the data sent as response in create query. Here is my code. It is not modifying.

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var app = module.exports = loopback();
module.exports = function(Container) {

  Container.beforeRemote('upload', function(context, user, next) {

    next();
  });


  Container.afterRemote('upload', function(context, affectedInstance, next) { 


    var container = affectedInstance.result.files.file[0].container;
    var val;
    if(container=='profilepic')
    {
    var fileName  = affectedInstance.result.files.file[0].name; 
    var FirstName= affectedInstance.result.fields.FirstName[0];
    var LastName = affectedInstance.result.fields.LastName[0];
    var Email = affectedInstance.result.fields.Email[0];
    var Password = affectedInstance.result.fields.Password[0];

        var account = Container.app.models.Account;
        account.create({
        FirstName:FirstName,
        LastName:LastName,
        Email:Email,
        Password:Password,
        UserPicture:'/server/storage/'+container+'/'+fileName,
        },function(err,ant){
        if(err)
        console.log(err);
        // Modifies the context
     var res= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ant));
     context.result={
        data:res
     }

     console.log(context.result); // result shows the desired value 
    });


    }





    next();
  });


};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have got the desired response. The problem was that the call back next() is executed before the modify operation. so i moved the next to the end of the create query.

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var app = module.exports = loopback();
module.exports = function(Container) {

  Container.beforeRemote('upload', function(context, user, next) {

    next();
  });


  Container.afterRemote('upload', function(context, affectedInstance, next) { 


    var container = affectedInstance.result.files.file[0].container;
    var val;
    if(container=='profilepic')
    {
    var fileName  = affectedInstance.result.files.file[0].name; 
    var FirstName= affectedInstance.result.fields.FirstName[0];
    var LastName = affectedInstance.result.fields.LastName[0];
    var Email = affectedInstance.result.fields.Email[0];
    var Password = affectedInstance.result.fields.Password[0];

        var account = Container.app.models.Account;
        account.create({
        FirstName:FirstName,
        LastName:LastName,
        Email:Email,
        Password:Password,
        UserPicture:'/server/storage/'+container+'/'+fileName,
        },function(err,ant){
        if(err)
        console.log(err);
        // Modifies the context
     var res= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ant));
     context.result={
        data:res
     }

     console.log(context.result); // result shows the desired value 
     next(); // Call back;
    });


    }
```

});

};